# Cognitive bias believing you are good at the things you are bad at, as successes are more vivid?

Tags: terminology, bias

What is the name for this cognitive bias?

### Scenario

I am bad at socializing with people. For 95% of the time I talked to people, I was very awkward. Yet, mostly only 5% of the opposite time stuck to my memory. Therefore I think that I'm a very social person. Although, overwhelmingly, I'm bad.

My mind is biased. I'm blind to all the times I failed, but can recount the outliers (successes) more vividly as if they were the norm.

---

Replace "socializing with people" with anything else.

PS: found and highlighted in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17LuaKpCoDw starting around 1:25

Comment: Social awkwardness cuts across a lot of issues and concepts. Why are you convinced that cognitive bias is relevant? Have you considered the more common issues of around neurodiversity (autism spectrum disorders, executive function differences, etc)? The other issue is the Dunning-Kruger effect which impacts everyone.

Comment: Having said all that, this question is subjective and not appropriate for SE. SE is not for questions that subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion - that is more appropriate for a discussion board style forum. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: Sounds like plain disillusionment to me. Not every error in reasoning needs to be attributed to a formal cognitive bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The self serving bias is the most likely bias at play. It affects what information we remember and how we interpret events. It ca  be used to explain  the dunning Krueger effect, which is the effect you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

It could be described as quite a few cognitive biases.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases.

For example, confirmation bias, illusory superiority or choice-supportive bias could be at work here in your description.